# Quartz Job Scheduling Complete

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have multiple QuartzJobBean in a Spring Framework application. These jobs are scheduled according to their needs. I have a problem like the following.

A job fires every 5 seconds.

Let's say;

```
1st execution at 00.00.05
2nd execution at 00.00.10
3rd execution at 00.00.15
.
.
.
etc.
```

However if 1st execution lasts 6 seconds, 2nd execution comes right after the first execution's completion. I want to schedule my jobs as the following if it is possible?

```
1st execution at 00.00.05 (execution time 6 seconds)
2nd execution at 00.00.16 (execution time 3 seconds)
3rd execution at 00.00.24 (execution time x seconds)
4th execution at 00.00.24+5+x 
.
.
.
etc.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up extending QuartzJobBean and also implementing StatefulJob. As trigger I used SimpleTriggerBean with repeatInterval property xxxx milliseconds.

MyJob class

```
public class MyJob extends QuartzJobBean implements StatefulJob
```

springcontext

```
<bean id="myJobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob"/>
    <property name="startDelay" value="0" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="2000" />
</bean>
```

Comment: @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation available now. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/new-in-quartz-2.html

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by having the job reschedule itself when it completes it's work.

You should be careful that if a job ends unexpectedly the rescheduling may not take place.

You could do that for example through listeners: [quartz job listener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/JobListeners)

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you already use Spring, you don't need Quartz at all. Quoting [*25.5.1 The @Scheduled Annotation*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled):

> #### 25.5.1 The @Scheduled Annotation
>
> The `@Scheduled` annotation can be added to a method along with trigger metadata. For example, the following method would be invoked every 5 seconds with a fixed delay, meaning that the period will be measured from the completion time of each preceding invocation.
>
> ```
> @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
> public void doSomething() {
>   // something that should execute periodically
> }
> ```

The example in the documentation seems to cover *exactly* what you want.

Comment: I don't use a version of Spring which includes this annotation actually. I ended up extending QuartzJobBean and also implementing StatefulJob.